# How to use protected IFeedbackMessageFilter[] getFilters() in wicket 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I am trying to convert below code from wicket-1.4.9 to wicket-6.x/7.x, but not getting solution. Please help in this as I am new to Apache Wicket

```
@Override
protected IFeedbackMessageFilter[] getFilters() {
    final List<IFeedbackMessageFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IFeedbackMessageFilter>();
    getPage().visitChildren(FeedbackPanel.class, new IVisitor<FeedbackPanel>() {

        @Override
        public Object component(FeedbackPanel component) {
            if (pageFeedback.equals(component)) {
                return CONTINUE_TRAVERSAL_BUT_DONT_GO_DEEPER;
            }
            filters.add(component.getFilter());
            return CONTINUE_TRAVERSAL;
        }
    });

    return filters.toArray(new IFeedbackMessageFilter[filters.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
@Override
protected IFeedbackMessageFilter[] getFilters() {
    final List<IFeedbackMessageFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IFeedbackMessageFilter>();

    getPage().visitChildren(FeedbackPanel.class, new IVisitor<FeedbackPanel, Void>() {

        @Override
        public void component(FeedbackPanel component, IVisit<Void> visit) {
            if (pageFeedback.equals(component)) {
                visit.dontGoDeeper();
                return;
            }
            filters.add(component.getFilter());
        }
    });

    return filters.toArray(new IFeedbackMessageFilter[filters.size()]);
```

}

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have a small querry

visit.dontGoDeeper();
                return;
is it same as return CONTINUE_TRAVERSAL_BUT_DONT_GO_DEEPER; ?

And how to write
 return CONTINUE_TRAVERSAL; 
it will be automatic?

Comment: Yes and yes! Please accept the answers once you are happy with them!

Comment: Am really happy with your way of answering my doubts, Thanks

Comment: Hi Martin, can you help me in this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963393/deployed-web-application-jdk-1-6-wicket-1-4-9-in-jboss-eap-7-0-getting-wicke